# Delphi Canvas Textout with RightToLeft BidiMode

Tags: delphi, canvas, bidi

I want to print Right-to-left Unicode strings on a Canvas. I can't find a BidiMode property or something like that to get it done.

currently the symbols which are located at the end of strings, appear before the first character of the text which is printed on the Canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## FMX

FireMonkey does not have any BiDi capabilities at this time.

## VCL

The [`Vcl.TControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl) class has public [`DrawTextBiDiModeFlags()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.DrawTextBiDiModeFlags) and [`DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly) methods, which help the control decide the appropriate BiDi flags to specify when calling the Win32 API [`DrawText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498.aspx) function.

In [`Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas), its [`TextOut()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextOut) and [`TextRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextRect) methods do not use the Win32 API `DrawText()` function, they use the Win32 API [`ExtTextOut()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713.aspx) function instead, where the value of the [`TCanvas.TextFlags`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextFlags) property is passed to the `fuOptions` parameter of `ExtTextOut()`. The `TextFlags` property also influences the value of the [`TCanvas.CanvasOrientation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.CanvasOrientation) property, which `TextOut()` and `TextRect()` use internally to adjust the X coordinate of the drawing.

For right-to-left drawing with `TCanvas`, include the `ETO_RTLREADING` flag in the `TextFlags` property.

Answer (score 0):

Had no success to display RTL text with "TextOut" when form bidimode is set to "bdLeftToRight", so I usually used 
XXX.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Text,[tfRtlReading,tfRight]);
Worked very well for me..
I needed to detect Hebrew, so I did it like this:

```
function CheckHebrew(s: string): boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if (ord(s[i])>=1424) and (ord(s[i])<1535) then
    begin
      Result := true;
      exit;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tf : TTextFormat;
  r : TRect;
  s : string;
begin
  r.Left := 0;
  r.Top := 0;
  r.Width := Image1.Width;
  r.Height := Image1.Height;
  s := Edit1.Text;
  if CheckHebrew(s) then
    tf := [tfRtlReading,tfRight,tfWordBreak]
  else
    tf := [tfWordBreak];
  Image1.Canvas.FillRect(r);
  Image1.Canvas.TextRect(r,s,tf)
end;
```

Comment: please post your full code it will be more easily to understand